# RoR - Call a new Action without a View on a form

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I created a new action on the `ClientsController` called `update_establishments`. I have a form for `Client` which I want to call that action without generating a new view. The action will generate a new view.

```
clients_controller.rb
     def update_establishments
       create_zip
       respond_to do |format|
       if @client.update(client_params)
         set_zip
         format.html { redirect_to @client, notice:'Estabelecimento adicionado com sucesso.'}
         format.json {head :no_content}
       else
         format.html { render action: 'edit'}
         format.json { render json: @client.error, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
    end
  end    


clients/_locations_form.html.erb

     form_for @client, :url=>{:action=>'update_establishments'}  do |form| %>
    ...
```

this throws an error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Clients#add_establishments`
with the explanation `No route matches {:action=>"update_establishments", :id=>"35", :controller=>"clients"}`

I made no changes on the `routes.rb`

Do I need to create a view called `clients/update_establishments` to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add new route to your `routes.rb` file, something like:

```
resources :clients do
  member do
   patch 'update_establishments'
  end
end
```

and update method 'patch' for your form:

`form_for @client, :url=>{:action=>'update_establishments'}, html: {method: "patch"} do |form|`